# I get a data type conversion error when running this code

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

But I am sure that the data types can work together, ItemID from 1 table is AutoNumber and a number in the other table.

```
Private Sub Command17_Click()

Dim cmbItem As String

cmbItem = "SELECT ItemID FROM Items WHERE Items.Name = " & Me.Combo0.Value & ";"

Dim sc1 As DAO.Recordset
Set sc1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Buy", dbOpenDynaset)

sc1.AddNew
sc1.Fields("ItemID").Value = cmbItem
sc1.Fields("BuyPrice").Value = Me.Text13.Value
sc1.Fields("Notes").Value = Me.Text18.Value
sc1.Update

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance,
Bob P

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the line which triggers your error ...

```
sc1.Fields("ItemID").Value = cmbItem
```

... notice that `cmbItem` is a string which contains a `SELECT` statment (`SELECT ItemID FROM ...`).  And you told us "*ItemID from 1 table is AutoNumber and a number in the other table*".  So you're attempting to assign a string value to a numeric field.  Furthermore, that string can't be cast to a valid number.  It has to fail.

Just guessing here, but maybe you want something like this ...

```
Dim cmbItem As Long
cmbItem = DLookup("ItemID", "Items", "[Name]=" & Me.Combo0.Value)
```

If `[Name]` is a text field, add quotes around the value you compare it to ...

```
cmbItem = DLookup("ItemID", "Items", "[Name]='" & Me.Combo0.Value & "'")
```

If that's close, you could rename the variable to `lngItem` so the code is less likely to confuse your collaborators.

If the `DLookup()` might return Null, consider feeding it to a `Nz()` expression.